# Why can't I view PNG images within an iOS application's bundle?

Tags: iphone, ios

When looking in a compiled .app bundle, I see PNG images used as resources for this application.  However, when I try to view them, they come up blank.

Why can't I view these PNG images from compiled iOS apps?  Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You should not use other people assets without their permission.**

You are running into the fact that PNG files are [optimized](http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2008/10/iphone-optimized-pngs.html) during the file copy phase of an iOS build. You have to revert the optimization to view them.

```
pngcrush -revert-iphone-optimizations <filename>
```

Apple has published a Tech note about [Viewing iPhone-Optimized PNGs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1681/_index.html).

Comment: They aren't crushed.  Crushed PNGs are simply PNGs that are optimised to be smaller.  Xcode changes the file format so that they aren't actually PNGs any more.  The format is similar, except the alpha channel is pre-multiplied.

Comment: Wrong, look at the copypng script it has this line in it. pngcrush -q -iphone.

Comment: Jim is right, the `pngcrush -q -iphone` phase converts the PNG into a slightly different format that premultiplies the alpha and changes the order of the components to be optimised for the iPhone's GPU.

Comment: -iphone (optimize for iPhone OS) and -revert-iphone-optimizations (convert iPhone OS optimized PNG to a PNG readable on other platforms) I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for answer, its just academic interesting.

Comment: "You should not use other people assets without their permission." Just like to note that you should not throw kittens off cliffs either.